# How to retrieve user's group/role using Waffle?

Tags: java, tomcat, waffle

I have setup Active Directory and would like to setup SSO. I am using Waffles and would like to know the user's group in my Servlet. How can I retrieve the user's group?

Answer (score 0):

I used the *WindowsPrincipal* to get the user's group.

```
WindowsPrincipal p = (WindowsPrincipal)request.getSession().getAttribute("waffle.servlet.NegotiateSecurityFilter.PRINCIPAL");

for(Map.Entry<String, WindowsAccount> entry: p.getGroups().entrySet()){
    System.out.println(entry.getValue().getName); //The is the group that the user memberOf
}
```